# Экранирование символов в регулярном выражении (дописываем свой текст)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d{2,5}
```

Можно сделать так, чтобы к найденному выражению по этому `regex` дописывался произвольный текст. Например:

```
127.0.0.1:8888@blalabla:blablabla
```

А не как сейчас:

```
127.0.0.1:8888
```

Comment: @lexone, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения не изменяют текст сами по себе. В большинстве движков есть операция замены текста, например, `s///` в Perl, `re.sub()` в Python.

Чтобы добавить текст после шаблона, можно использовать [`\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542950/4279): `s/шаблон\K/добавка/`, например, чтобы добавить `@bla` после `ip:port` во входном тексте:

```
$ echo 'a 127.0.0.1:8888 z' |
  perl -pe 's/(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\:\d{2,5}\K/\@bla/g'
```

Результат:

```
a 127.0.0.1:8888@bla z
```

Если библиотека регулярных выражений в данном языке не поддерживает `\K`, тогда можно использовать захват группы (c помощью `()`) и ссылаться на группу с помощью `$1`, `\1` в зависимости от regexp диалекта. Пример на Питоне:

```
$ echo 'a 127.0.0.1:8888 z' |
  python -c 'import re, sys; 
    print(re.sub(r"((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\:\d{2,5})", r"\1@bla", sys.stdin.read()))'
```

Тот же результат:

```
a 127.0.0.1:8888@bla z
```

Так как `\K` не используется, то в выражение для замены необходимо добавить `\1`, которое вставляет захваченную группу текста.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d{2,5}.*
```

Comment: Не совсем меня поняли)
Нужно чтобы добавлялся текст к полученному regex (его нету там, где мы парсим).

Comment: @lexone я не совсем понял, что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге. Покажите какой-нибудь наглядный пример.

Comment: Есть текст на странице
127.0.0.1:8888
127.0.0.1:1111
122.0.0.1:8888

Мне нужно регуляркой вытянуть значения любой строки и дописать к нему свой текст
Например
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d{2,5}@мой текст:мой текст

Спарсит оно так
122.0.0.1:8888@мой текст:мой текст

Comment: То есть экранирование символов в самой регулярке.

Comment: Регулярные выражения не умеют ничего дописывать. Они проверяют текст на соответствие шаблону.

Comment: Может, и так, но я видел такую регулярку, которая дописывала 3 буквы к полученному результату (руб), то есть на голом regex, без всяких замен $1